# AutoMapper sets related entities to null despite using opt => opt.Ignore()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

I am trying to map two objects of the same type through AutoMapper (most recent version installed through NuGet). My code:

```
public class School
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name{get; set;}
    public User CreatedBy {{get; set;}
}

public class User
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Code {get; set;}
}
```

I have EF 6 with MVC. In edit, a copy of School is given to the view and when it is submitted, I am trying to map it to the one in the database so that I can save it. I don't want to change the User in School while mapping. So my code is:

In Edit Controller Action

```
//...
var school = db.Schools.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == viewModel.SchoolId);

Mapper.CreateMap<School, School>().ForMember(r => r.User, opt => opt.Ignore());
//viewModel.School is an object of School type.
school = Mapper.Map<School>(viewModel.School);
//Here school.User is set to null!
```

Amazed to see school.User is null. I thought I have given express exclusion to the mapper to ignore the destination value. I presume in such cases, it should retain the source property. I have also tried UseDestinationValue() instead. But no luck. What's causing this error? I sometimes wonder if any other better approach is available for EF-specific object mapping.

Comment: Assuming your mapping from entity to viewmodel, you could try the different option:  Mapper.Map(viewModel.School, school);  You might want to qualify the 2 different schools in CreateMap to make it clear.

Comment: You're completely reassigning `school` every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because you are creating a new instance of school rather than updating the one you've pulled from the database.

Instead of:

```
var school = db.Schools.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == viewModel.SchoolId);
school = Mapper.Map<School>(viewModel.School);
```

Do:

```
var school = db.Schools.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == viewModel.SchoolId);
Mapper.Map(viewModel.School, school);
```

Rather than creating a new instance, this will update the one you already have.

As an aside, you should not be creating maps in your action methods - this should be run in your application initialisation, as it does not need to run on each method.